# Condition for a SQL query to check if dates are between prior period and current month and execute subqueries based on given gate

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @Todaydate DATE
SET @Todaydate = '12/31/2017'

SELECT
    CASE 
       WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,@Todaydate,getdate()) >= 31 
          THEN (SELECT a.CU, , b.abc
                FROM histhold a, security b
                WHERE T_QUANTITY_P <> 0
                  AND ACCOUNTING_DATE = '04/30/2018'
                  AND a.cu = b.CU)
          ELSE ''
    END
```

Comment: Tag properly!!!  MySQL doesn't use T-SQL.  Which one are you using?????

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

Just do the logic in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT a.CU, , b.abc
FROM histhold a
    INNER JOIN security b
       ON a.cu = b.CU
WHERE T_QUANTITY_P <> 0
    AND ACCOUNTING_DATE = '04/30/2018'
    AND DATEDIFF(dd,@Todaydate,getdate()) >= 31;
```

Unless this is part of some larger procedure/script I can't imagine a reason why you would only want to execute a query given certain conditions (as opposed to executing the query and restricting the results based on those conditions potentially returning an empty recordset).